# pdflatex: How to find out if reruns are necessary?

Tags: endnotes

I run pdflatex.exe from an app (c#) of mine with Process.Start(....).

The endnote facility apparently makes reruns necessary.

pdflatex does not automatically do reruns, if I'm right.
So I want to do that via c#.
How can I detect if a rerun is necessary?
I hear the log file has some indications of this necessity.
Do I have to scan the .log file? or....?
I don't want to use latexmk, because that would complicate distribution too much.

Comment: Have you looked at a log file?  It's not too bad for a document without errors.  latexmk is usually distributed along with pdflatex, so I don't know that it would be adding that much complication (especially compared to trying to process the log file).

Comment: customer would have to install perl too, no ?

Comment: Probably depends on the system you are running on. On Cygwin (TeX Live) I see a mklatex.pl so yes perl required on Windows (MiKTeX) I see latexmk.ex but when I tried to run it I saw it tried to load latexmk.pl as well. So looks like perl is also required.

Comment: There are different build tools running on different programming languages: `latexmk` (Perl), `rubber` (Python), `arara` (Java). Or just run LaTeX twice always, or three times if you want to be sure.